# How to login to SSL website using java without having the server certificate

Tags: java, ssl, https

I am able to connect to https url using java. But my concern is to log in to a SSL website by providing username and password. I have done it using the PostMethod of HTTP Client, but not sure how the same can be achieved for HTTPS URL's?

Comment: Login using HTTP auth or a custom login of a website?

Comment: @SimoneGianni i did not get it can you please elaborate on your answer, as its a HTTPS website only and i cant login using http.

Comment: You say you call a post method for login, this sounds like you're calling some kind of server side script for login. Another way of managing authentication on HTTP is to use HTTP auth (basic, digest etc..). Which one of the two are you using? Calling a server side script or dealing with HTTP basic auth?